# creating a group of controls

Tags: c#, winforms, conditional-statements

I ran into little problem today as I was working on my game...
The problem is I have this condition running on 1 milisecond timer :

```
if (jump == true && 
    jumped == 0 && 
   (Player.Location == new Point(Player.Location.X, Block1.Location.Y - Player.Height) || 
    Player.Top == this.Height - Player.Height))
{
   do something...
}
```

The "Block1" is one object in the game (Picturebox) and I need like 10 or 20 or even 100 more of these blocks with the same condition, so how could I simplify it? It would be 50 or even more lines of one condition. Basically I would like to know if there is a way of mixing all **"Blocks" (pictureboxes) into a group** (named Blocks) or something I could still access with **Blocks.Location.Y etc**

Comment: Why 1ms timer? You'll also run into issues if the code execution takes longer since then you'll be running the function in parallel on multicore/CPU machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many conditions in this single check, IMO. I'd break them down and then work on each condition in a stand-alone manner which will make things easier to debug as well as to read/comprehend in the future.

```
// Too much going on here; let's refactor.
if (jump == true 
    && jumped == 0 
    && (Player.Location == new Point(Player.Location.X, Block1.Location.Y - Player.Height) 
        || Player.Top == this.Height - Player.Height))
{
   //do something...
}
```

Instead of creating a large if statement, pull the conditions into a single method:

```
// first refactor
private bool IsValidForSomeAction()
{
    if(!jump)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(jumped != 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(Player.Top == this.Height - Player.Height)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (Player.Location == new Point(Player.Location.X, Block1.Location.Y - Player.Height))
    {
       return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

After the first refator, it becomes clear that there is no need to create a new Point for the final comparison:

```
// second refactor
private bool IsValidForSomeAction()
{
    if(!jump)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(jumped != 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(Player.Top == this.Height - Player.Height)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // only the Y location matters, no need to create a new Point for the comparison.
    if (Player.Location.Y == Block1.Location.Y - Player.Height)
    {
       return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now, let's focus on what really matters: `if (Player.Location.Y == Block1.Location.Y - Player.Height)`. The condition boils down to the difference between the Block's Y location and the Player's Height.

Given that there may be 10, 20, 50, or 100+ Blocks to compare, then create a private field containing a collection of all the Blocks.

```
// override the onload event and find all the picture boxes:

private readonly List<PictureBox> _boxes = new List<PictureBox>();

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);    

    _boxes.AddRange(this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()
}
```

The `_boxes` field can then be used for the final validation:

```
// third refactor
private bool IsValidForSomeAction()
{
    if(!jump)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(jumped != 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(Player.Top == this.Height - Player.Height)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // only the Y location matters, no need to create a new Point for the comparison.
    if(_boxes.Any(x => x.Location.Y - Player.Height == Player.Location.Y)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Really thanks for that group of boxes (to do the other stuff i would have to re-do everything, but thanks for that too)
I hope you enjoyed the Christmas :P

Comment: Welcome to S.O. If this answer helps, then upvote and/or accept the answer and have a Merry X-Mas as well :)